# Convert an Object array to a Float array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, converters

I have an object array with 256 elements which needs to be converted into a float array.

How do I convert an Object array into a float array in C# with minimal performance penalty?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about _code optimisations_ (_"...with minimal performance penalty"_) are off-topic. See _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_ and  _[Is it okay to ask for code optimization help?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-code-optimization-help)_ for more information.

Comment: _"How do I convert an Object array into a float array in C#"_ -- that depends on what those objects actually are, which you neglected to state in your post. _"with minimal performance penalty?"_ -- arguably off-topic, typically "lacks focus", and at best requires a question that makes clear what you've tried already, what specifically you need help with, and a clear statement about how you've determined that performance is inadequate, and what performance goal is expected/required.

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about performance, it's best not to box a *value type* (i.e `object`) in the first instance. Note, that using the `object` or `dynamic` type is *"sometimes"* indicative of a design issue that should be solved first.

However, assuming they are just boxed floats. You can just use [`Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-5.0):

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

```
var floatArray = objectArray.Cast<float>().ToArray();
```

If the objects aren't just boxed floats, yet implements the `IConvertible` *interface* you might have to take more drastic action and use the one of the convert methods like `ChangeType` or `ToSingle`.

> Returns an object of the specified type and whose value is equivalent
> to the specified object.
>
> ...
>
> ChangeType is a general-purpose conversion method that converts the
> object specified by value to conversionType. The value parameter can
> be an object of any type, and conversionType can also be a Type object
> that represents any base or custom type. For the conversion to
> succeed, value must implement the IConvertible interface, because the
> method simply wraps a call to an appropriate IConvertible method. The
> method requires that conversion of value to conversionType be
> supported.

```
var objects = new List<object>(){ "3", 2m ,3L,"5.5"};
var floatArray = objects.Select(x => (float)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(float))).ToArray();
```

<sub>***Note** : This is fairly inefficient.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it, this is one way. ObjectArray being the array of objects. This code does not check if the object can be converted to a single.

```
var result = objectArray.Select(o=> Convert.ToSingle(o)).ToArray();
```

[Microsoft documentation for ToSingle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tosingle?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToSingle_System_Object_)